# Pymongo How to I extract the data

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

My (python)MongoDB has `ISODate("2014-10-11T10:51:00.000Z")` format:

```
{
    "_id" : 2360836,
    "created_at" : ISODate("2014-10-11T10:51:00.000Z"),
}
```

I want to get data between `2014-09-01` to `2014-12-09`.
How can I do get the records from the MongoDB?
I prefer use as the mysql.

Comment: can I use aggregrate() function to do it?

Comment: Why will you want that? what is wrong with the given answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
import datetime
import pymongo
conn = pymongo.MongoClient()
db = conn.test #test is my database
col = db.bar #bar is my collection
col.find_one({"created_at": {"$gt" : datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 1), "$lt": datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 9)}})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime.strptime('2014-09-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
end = datetime.datetime.strptime('2014-09-01', '%Y-%m-%d')


c = MongoClient()
db = c['<your db name>']

for doc in db.<your collection>.find({'created_at': {'$gt': start, '$lt': end}}):
    # do things
    print doc
```

You can check the [documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html#range-queries) on this.